# Coordenadas en Bokeh Maps

Tags: python, bokeh

Alguien ha utilizado el módulo bokeh.tile_providers ?
Encuentro este simple ejemplo:

```
output_file("tile.html")

tile_provider = get_provider(Vendors.CARTODBPOSITRON)

# range bounds supplied in web mercator coordinates
p = figure(x_range=(-2000000, 6000000), y_range=(-1000000, 7000000),
       x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")
p.add_tile(tile_provider)

show(p)
```

Supuestamente, los parámetros x_range e y_range los debería extraer de https://epsg.io/ pero no puedo encontrar los exactos para Argentina. No sé, realmente, si tengo que realizar un cálculo a los mismos. He leído y probado varias formas y ninguna me funciona.
Le agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Bokeh usa como sistema de coordenadas la conocida como proyección [Web Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection) (Google Maps, OpenStreetMap). Tiene varios nombres alternativos, puedes seleccionarla en [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/) como WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las coordenadas para Argentina serían en principio:

> -7079779.598466, -4941570.411656

Pero debes especificar un rectángulo, por ejemplo:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.tile_providers import get_provider, Vendors


output_file("tile.html")

tile_provider = get_provider(Vendors.CARTODBPOSITRON)

# range bounds supplied in web mercator coordinates
p = figure(x_range=(-7717082, -6343661), y_range=(-4092133, -4739095),
       x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")
p.add_tile(tile_provider)

show(p)
```

con lo que Bokeh nos genera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ten en cuenta que `x_range=(-7717082, -6343661), y_range=(-4092133, -4739095)` representan las coordenadas que delimitan el rectángulo del mapa a mostrar, en este caso:

- Punto superior-izquierdo (NW): `x: -7717082, y: -4092133`
- Punto inferior-derecho (SE): `x: -6343661, y: -4739095`

Comment: Te agradezco la respuesta y solución. Lo he intentado hoy siguiendo los mismos pasos pero, simplemente, cuando selecciono a Argentina, no obtengo esas coordenadas. Entonces, tampoco puedo armar el  rectángulo. Todos los parámetros los obtienes de   https://epsg.io ??? Gracias!

Comment: Lau en el mapa tienes que modificar el sistema de coordenadas haciendo click en el botón `change` que marco con la flecha en la imagen de la respuesta y elegir WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator. Por defecto usa WGS 84  que es el usado por el sistema GPS . Cuando cambies esto, solo coloca la "mirilla" que aparece en el centro del sitio sobre los puntos y arriba tienes las coordenadas de ese punto. Ten en cuenta que además puedes convertir entre sistemas en https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3857

Comment: Haciendo  eso, y hoy lo he repetido varias veces, no obtengo esos datos. Te agradezco igual, verdaderamente, me cansó.

Comment: Te dejo un enlace con el sistema ya configurado: https://epsg.io/map#srs=3857&x=-6508765.832539&y=-4114146.610421&z=6&layer=streets

Comment: XD! Me expresé mal e interpreté que estábamos mencionando a los valores de x_range e y_range.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo. Pensé que había una forma exacta de calcular esos valores.